# Send Message with user mention to MS Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams, webhooks, adaptive-cards

I want to send a simple message which will mention user via MS Teams Webhook connector.

I can send Adaptive Card with this

```
{
"type": "message",
"attachments": [
    {
    "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
    "content": {
        "type": "AdaptiveCard",
        "body": [
            {
                "type": "TextBlock",
                "size": "Medium",
                "weight": "Bolder",
                "text": "Card title here"
            },
            {
                "type": "TextBlock",
                "text": "<at>Name AAD</at> - Message here"
            }
        ],
        "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
        "version": "1.0",
        "msteams": {
            "entities": [
                {
                    "type": "mention",
                    "text": "<at>Name AAD</at>",
                    "mentioned": {
                      "id": "xxx",
                      "name": "Name"
                    }
                  }
            ]
        }
    }
}]
}
```

But the width of the Adaptive Card is not customizable and I'd like to send just a simnple message without any additional color changes or text formatting. Like the latest message in this [picture](https://i0.wp.com/tracyvanderschyff.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/2017-10-05-23_16_12-feature-requests-governance-forum-_-microsoft-teams.png?ssl=1).

Comment: You can use ["width": "Full"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-format?tabs=adaptive-md%2Cdesktop%2Cconnector-html#full-width-adaptive-card) property to make the card render in full width. We did add width property to the JSON shared by you and see the cards as below. The text added by you in TextBlock renders like a plain message without any additional color changes. 

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ad7jS.png

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT - This worked but it's limited by a bug. https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues/7638

Comment: Bug has been raised for the above-mentioned issue and engineering team is looking into it. Please follow the above Github thread for further updates on the bug.